# How to run php file through command line?

Tags: php, websocket

I am learning creating Websockets in PHP. I have code for client side and for server side file as well. I want to learnt how to run php files through command line. Can anyone please provide me step by step solution for the same?

Comment: It depends a lot on the server but what have you tried? `php /home/user/public_html/script.php arg1 arg2`

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow** `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` Please take a tour [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I am running windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows, make sure you have PHP installed and type this into a command prompt:

`C:\Path\To\php.exe C:\Path\To\Your\script.php`

(source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php)

And on Linux/Unix:
`php /path/to/script.php`

Comment: Tried this but not working. It is getting disconnected.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your code. Would you care sharing your code?